# EasyPHP MySQL does not start

Tags: c++, mysql, easyphp

I´ve installed EasyPHP Devserver 16.1.1 on Windows 7 starter. HTTP server works fine, but MySQL (5.7.11 x86) doesn't start. I can't figure out why. After clicking Start button, the page refreshes but MySQL never starts, with no error messages. Error log remains empty.
I´ve also installed Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2015 x86.
Can anyone help me with this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the reason.I read MYSQL's error log , and saw this "[ERROR] Do you already have another mysqld server running on port: 3306 ?" , then I realized that I have another mysql server is running on 3306(because I have installed other PHP environment in my computer,and it starts automatically). I open the Tools of EasyPHP ,select "open ports controller", and kill the process on 3306. Finally , I start MYSQL again. Everything goes fine.

Comment: thanx for your answer. But that wasn't, my case, since EasyPHP was my first attempt. I use now Xampp, installed later, and it works fine :)

Comment: EasyPHP was easy when it was v13. I installed EasyPHP v17 on two computers and it is not working at all. :/ I am dissapointed.

Answer (score -1):

i opened the CMD and wrote "lodctr /r", i waited to load a few second, a message popped out, i dont remember what it said but then i reloaded the web site and tried again to star the servers, it worked!!!

well, if anybody is having problems here can try this.